# View over ListView leads to ClassCast Exception

Tags: android, android-listview, classcastexception, ondraw

I am using a Relative Layout(RL) to Hold a List View(lv) and a few bunch of other widgets like Text View(tv), Edit Text(et), then a few Buttons(btn) and finally one Progress Bar(pb). 

**Scenarios**
 **1.** When i add child Views to the Parent Container View viz. Relative Layout(rl), in the order:
 **RL(Btn1->Btn2->tv1->tv2->LV->pb).**
 Then we have no problem, i mean No Exception, No Problem.
 **2.** But when i do the ordering change like 
 **RL(tv1->tv2->LV->Btn1->Btn2->pb).**
 then i am getting a classcast Exception.

Note: the two buttons should be over the listview, as both of them are social website buttons, i mean Facebook and Twitter.

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlfornews"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/newsbg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbasetw"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbasefb"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnbasetw"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnewscon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/newstitle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="@string/news"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvfornews"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvnewscon"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_data_found"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvdashboardnews"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvnewscon"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbfornews"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: The Progress Bar might be below, but it is just to user information, that some data is loading. and when i get that data, i am making its Visibility to VIEW.GONE state, and the List View being already there !
My question is when i follow the First Scenario, even though i have a Progress Bar from the entire time, i am not getting a Class Cast Exception. But i am getting the exception, when i change to Scenario 2. So why i am i getting it?

Comment: where you got the ClassCastException ? can you post the Error log. And tray to clean the project after changing the items order. some times its Eclipse problem

Comment: I got the error log, at
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
with the lv equating to the Button's id !!
I can't paste the log cat, as the project is not with me now. but i have studied it well enough to make a trail, but it will take time, anyway i will try to post logs asap.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure about these but may be the reason is you have used the android:layout_below = "@id/textview" instead of use these android:layout_below = "@+id/textview" all UI.
2. If you can do these UI using the LinearLayout.

Comment: Its ok, as the Second TextView Doesn't take much space, and it is to appear, when the listview fails to fetch data from service. At that point, the ListView is forced to go into VISIBILITY.GONE State.
Also, i need it to be a RelativeLayout, as i want to position the widgets according to their Parent's Relative Location.